# Noisy ventilation when cold outside

Tags: ventilation

Odd question from one that understands nothing about airflow, but has been obsessing over an issue for a while.

I live in a cold area, and when it's around F -4 (or C -20) or colder outside the noise from my ventilation fixtures (the holes with adjustable lids) on the wall increases dramatically. This is true for the outgoing airflow but even more for the ingoing air. As far as I understand, indoors/outdoors disparity should have no ear-detectable effect on ventilation. I can feel an increased airflow with my hands around the fixtures aswell. On warmer days it's silent.

What is going on? I can tell it isn't related to wind, as I've installed a wind meter and logged measurements for a while now. Plus, windy conditions is rare where I live. The only thing I can think of are multiple fans getting frosted up and making scratching noise but I'm not entirely sure that makes sense either as the humidity is abysmal, especially on these cold days. I can only think of a mechanical failure of some sort.

The place is a rental apartment building, floor 5/9, 4 apartments of around 750 sqf (70 sqm) per floor. The indoor temperature on these cold days is around F 74 (or C 23). The fixtures (hole in the wall with a partially covering lid) are spotless clean and the airducts have recently been cleaned.

I could, against the rules of my rental contract, screw the lids to reduce the noise but instead mess with the air quality. I'm not really looking for a solution more of a plausible explanation.

*Note: English isn't my first language and speaking ventilation has proven hard. I'm sorry and I hope you understand.*

Comment: Cold does cause stuff to shrink, so if that cold air gets into any metal work, it could be a factor.  Heating systems also need to work harder/more to keep up.  Hopefully I don't see those temps for a few more months.

Comment: Without knowing what the holes in the walls connect to, it's hard to speculate with any hope of accuracy. It may be that a supplemental heat supply is needed to warm the incoming air at those temperatures, and it's not switched on until it's that cold.

Comment: @crip659 Maybe. No those temps are not pleasant at all. :)

Comment: @Ecnerwal I'm fairly sure there's no supplemental heating. My landlord (which is a massive red-tape-ridden company) will unfortunately not supply any information on anything unless legally required to do so. :(

Comment: Do you know if there is some kind of FAN inside ? Does it works in both direction, intake and exhaust.

Answer (score 1):

Without more information, I suspect your apartment may have a multi-stage furnace that moves more air through the ducts when it is very cold outside.

For example, the furnace for my home has a "first stage" and a "second stage". If the temperature outdoors is not much colder than the temperature indoors, the furnace will intentionally operate at a lower fan speed and with fewer active burners, because it does not need to work as hard. This is the first stage. It is designed to heat your home gradually and comfortably.

However, if it is very cold outside, the furnace will switch to the second stage, which moves more air through the ducts and (in my case) also uses all of the burners for maximum heating power, at the expense of noise and potentially unbalanced temperatures indoors until air has circulated sufficiently between all the rooms.

In first stage, I only know the furnace is running because I can feel the gentle air currents. In second stage, the return (intake to furnace) grill becomes loud and the registers (outlet from furnace) become audible from air movement.

The furnace automatically switches between off, first stage, and second stage via the thermostat's built-in logic. It's not supposed to be user adjustable. Second stage only activates if it is taking a long time to reach the desired temperature, or if the temperature difference between the current temperature and the desired temperature is larger than a few degrees. Otherwise, it operates in first stage only, gradually heating at a lower rate to stay unobtrusive. I've also heard that first stage is a little more fuel-efficient despite running for longer periods of time, but the two-stage system is really designed for better comfort first and foremost.

There may be other explanations but this is the one that makes the most sense to me.

It *could* also be something to do with a heat recovery system (which brings fresh air into your apartment, but heats it by extracting the heat from the outgoing stale air), but I'll let someone with more knowledge of those systems discuss them. We don't tend to have them in the United States where I live. :(

Answer (score 0):

Cold air is heavier,denser, than warm air. There will be more friction with moving cold air and therefore more noise. You mentioned fans, fans will bind up a bit in cold temperatures. The bearings will be a little sluggish and the fans will have to work harder moving the denser air. Think about how your car starts when it's below zero out. It takes a while for it to heat up and run smooth.

Comment: My modern petrol-powered Volvo fortunately doesn't mind cold temperatures at all but I do get your point. I suppose many little things add up but the mentioned temperatures seem to make a much more evident threshold somehow.

Comment: Friction-wise I'd imagined it was the other way around. Hot formula one wheels makes for great traction, cold not so much.

Comment: @MoMononoke nice to see a happy Volvo owner, I have one and like it much